# Is any possibility to the zend project work on localhost without virtual host?

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework

I have researched a lot for just display 'Hello World' in my zend application.I still get a blank page.I want to run the code in localhost without setting a virtual host.Please suggest a solution or configuration for that.Am having the project in localhost/demoproject.

Comment: Move files from `public` folder to main folder. Don't forget to change paths accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get your application running with virtual host then simple answer to your question would be.

use `localhost/demoproject/public/` as the url. Default Zend projects have their `index.php` file as `project/public/index.php` so you will need to use the url above to run the index.php which is the gateway to your framework.

If you are having other errors then make sure you're error display is turned on for development environment or check your error message in error log and post it here.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your zend files on library folder from project...

And go to System Var and set the path to this folder.